# Multiple Fusion Middleware (different releases) installations on the same server

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, weblogic, oracle-fusion-middleware

I already have one working release (11g R2) of the Oracle Fusion Middleware installed, with WebLogic 11g R1 . I'd like to install a different release of the Fusion Middleware (with it's own WebLogic, also a different release than the previously mentioned) on the same server, but I'd like to be sure it won't screw up my working set up.

My inclination is to set up different users to handle the different environmental variables, and also use a different set of ports. Is this a correct approach or should I consider anything else that I might be overlooking?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want different releases on the same server?

Comment: I require different releases because i need to install several software that is supported by different versions of WebLogic and Middleware. I could do It using different servers but that would a bit of a waste of hardware.

Comment: It's 2017. Why is physical hardware even an issue? Just run them up in VMs or docker or whatever you normally use to provision boxes.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, but I don't feel like having two VMs each with a 40GB virtual disk.

Comment: Well, different users is probably the best way to do it, then.